# Is a YAML set key possible and if so, what does it look like?

Tags: set, key, yaml

From what I understand so far, a YAML set key would look like...

```
? thing1
? thing2
? thing3
: value
```

Is this accurate?

update: I put that code into yamllint.com and got...

```
--- 
thing1: ~
thing2: ~
thing3: value
```

I don't think that's what I wanted :( .

Comment: You should use code sample and correctly indent your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize. Doing that now...

Comment: Also, make sure you check out these helpful tools:
http://www.yamllint.com/
which will validate your YAML code
and
http://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv
which will let you convert YAML to i.e. JSON to make sure it has correct output

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Try explaining a bit more. Could you write a JSON version of what you want to achieve or maybe a pseudo code version?

Comment: I might be slightly ignorant on this subject. I simply want to be able to make keys that are not sequences, strings or formatted strings but are actual sets. I'm building a kind of toy project that pastes together resume text by selecting tagged content.

Comment: I recommend checking out the spec for YAML 1.2 http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Preview
it is pretty easy to follow and I think you will find your answers there pretty quickly. I think it sounds a bit off using anything other than strings as keys in YAML. But I may have misunderstood your intent.

Comment: It's fine. Thanks for your help PerMafrost. I guess a string really is the best way to go. I'll die happy though if I can use sets. I really don't care if it can decompose into JSON (not to hate on JSON).

Answer (score 0):

A set is not a base complex type of YAML. Those are only scalars, mappings and sequences. For a [set](http://yaml.org/type/set.html) you actually need ? to indicate a key so you can leave out the null value ( `: null` or old-style `: ~`).

What you fail to do is combine the set elements into a single key, and this is, once more, done by using a `?` to make the key start explicit:

```
? 
  ? thing1
  ? thing2
  ? thing3
: value
```

If you validate this you will notice that yamllint.com will make this into the less readable, but equivalent:

```
--- 
? 
  thing1: ~
  thing2: ~
  thing3: ~
: value
```